# Regex match between and including special ANSI ESC control character

Tags: javascript, regex, special-characters

I have a log file being generated from the output to stderr from a javascript based node application. 
(output to the txt file is from a grunt plugin called 'logfile-grunt' to be precise)

other parts of the javascript program are generating a 'progress bar' on the console output.
In the console output, the progress bar is just a single line that keeps getting updated, but in the logfile each and every state of the progress bar is recorded in the logfile surrounded by some sort of special characters i think are ANSI escape codes: `ESC[1G` at the start of each line and `ESC[0K`, where 'ESC' is a single symbol.

I would like to use regex to go through the logfile and match everything from the progress bar including the escape codes and remove it.

What is a javascript regex expression that will match this ?

example output in log file as displayed in Sublime text as plain text:

```
    uploading images
    NUMBER OF IMAGE FILES: 406
    ESC[1G[--------------------------------------------------] 1/406ESC[0K
    ESC[1G[=-------------------------------------------------] 2/406ESC[0K
    ESC[1G[==------------------------------------------------] 3/406ESC[0K
    ESC[1G[===-----------------------------------------------] 4/406ESC[0K
    ESC[1G[====----------------------------------------------] 5/406ESC[0K
    -----------------------------------------------
    >> Task completed, blah blah
```

After using a regex based find and replace tool i want the file to look like:

```
    uploading images
    NUMBER OF IMAGE FILES: 406
    -----------------------------------------------
    >> Task completed, blah blah
```

Its just the regex expresion to match the progress bar lines with the special control charaters i need to match

**EDIT**
showing the output example with line numbers indicated:

```
    1    uploading images
    2    NUMBER OF IMAGE FILES: 406
    3    ESC[1G[--------------------------------------------------] 1/406ESC[0K
         ESC[1G[=-------------------------------------------------] 2/406ESC[0K
         ESC[1G[==------------------------------------------------] 3/406ESC[0K
         ESC[1G[===-----------------------------------------------] 4/406ESC[0K
         ESC[1G[====----------------------------------------------] 5/406ESC[0K
    4    -----------------------------------------------
    5    >> Task completed, blah blah
```

Comment: /\x1b\[1G(.*)\x1b\[0K/g seems to be selecting what i need. \x1b selects the ANSI escape character, \[ selects the square bracket followed by 1G literally selected .... then anything with (.*) until the  ESC[0K selected with \x1b\[0K. as there are a few sections of the log file with this text i want to remove the regex is finished with /g to indicate that i want more than just the first match.

Comment: you may also want to include a '\n' at the end to remove the line breaks (depending on your replacement works)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing to realise was that i was trying to match ANSI escape codes which are prefixed with the `ESC` character.
As such to match the ESC character, which is ASCII character 1B in hexadecimal, the selector is `\x1b`.

so my regex became

`/\x1b\[1G.*\x1b\[0K/g`

Answer (score 0):

Since the data appears to always be well-formed, you can take the approach of matching the specific strings you know will be present and group everything in between.

```
(FILES: \d+\n)([\s\S]*\n(\s)*)-
```

In this case, you would just replace the second capturing group with '' to achieve what you are looking for or you could replace the full match with $1 to re-include the number of files and the line break.

Comment: This seems to select starting at 'FILES' and then does everything after that including lines I don't want to remove